# How to get multiple regex matches capture group

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to access all matches of my first capture group `([^ ]+)` in an array so I can `foreach` it, however I don't see it in the output:

```
$input = "Row 1:
Computer: xxx
Last Heartbeat: 4/9/2020 11:27:24 AM

Row 2:
Computer: yyy
Last Heartbeat: 4/9/2020 11:27:37 AM"

$matches = ([regex]'Computer: ([^ ]+)').Matches($input)
$matches
```

Yields:

```
Groups   : {0, 1}
Success  : True
Name     : 0
Captures : {0}
Index    : 7
Length   : 13
Value    : Computer: xxx

Groups   : {0, 1}
Success  : True
Name     : 0
Captures : {0}
Index    : 66
Length   : 13
Value    : Computer: yyy
```

Admittedly I have a lot to learn about the data structures and how to access them.

Comment: `$input` is an enumerator which provides access to the pipeline you have. Name your variable in a different way. Also, I think you need `Computer:\s*(\S+)` pattern.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew:  I didn't think this mattered but seems `[^ ]` matches either a `\n` or `\r` or combination in PS?  Worked in VSCODE a cmd prompt but not PS ISE.  Different in PCRE?

Comment: VScode uses a weird modification of the latest ECMAScript 2018 regex, the usual patterns may work differently there. `[^ ]` matches any char but a regular space. So, it matches CR, LF, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Before we get to the real answer, please consider renaming your variables - both `$Matches` and `$Input` are [automatic and can be overwritten by the runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables).*

---

In order to grab the value of the first capture group, you'll want to address index 1 in the `Groups` property or index 0 in the `Captures` property of each match:

```bsh
$string = "Row 1:
Computer: xxx
Last Heartbeat: 4/9/2020 11:27:24 AM

Row 2:
Computer: yyy
Last Heartbeat: 4/9/2020 11:27:37 AM"

$results = ([regex]'Computer: ([^ ]+)').Matches($string)
$results | ForEach-Object { $_.Groups[1].Value }
# or 
$results | ForEach-Object { $_.Captures[0].Value }
```

Comment: Thanks.  Is there any way to see the structure of my `$matches` or is the MS docs the only way?  Like a `var_dump` in PHP.

Comment: `$var |ConvertTo-Json` will get you some way (be aware the `MatchInfo` data structure returned by `Regex.Matches` has cyclic references). `$var |Format-List * -Force` will give you all first-level properties (regardless of default formatting) and `$var |Get-Member` will show which properties and methods are available on each item in `$var`